# List of API Level - Devices and SDK Versions in android

Tags: android, components, versions

Is there a definitive list of features and their supposed API & SDK versions and supported Mobile devices?

Basically, when I want to use a features, lets say `Tabs` or `SwipeViews`, I want to see if its supported in Gingerbread version, etc. Simple!

If there is a page / site, that lists or allows me to search, that is what I am looking for.

I am having hard time finding this, even in Android documentation pages.

Comment: You can filter the pages by API level to see if a class / method is supported. As for Devices, I'm not aware of any reliable definitive list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can easily see which API something was added in by looking at it's documentation.

For example, in the [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) documentation, you can see that it has existed since API 3, as it is mentioned on the right edge of the screen, in the same line as the title:

[image]

For individual methods and constants etc, you can scroll down to their documentation and see when they were added:

[image]

Here you can see that [SERIAL_EXECUTOR](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#SERIAL_EXECUTOR) and [THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR) were added in API 11, while the [constructor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#AsyncTask%28%29) and [cancel()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#cancel%28boolean%29) have existed since API 3

Comment: Though not a perfect answers. This helps a bit with what I am looking for Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_%28operating_system%29) (scroll down to section 5.1, "Usage Share") for API/SDK versions.

Then use the [Android Device Gallery](http://www.android.com/devices/) and browse devices by version number to obtain supported devices.  (Note: the option to filter devices by their version number is contained in the spinner that looks like an Android device's overflow menu).